# Is it a good practice to add custom method on Laravel Model class to insert record in another table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am following a tutorial to create a referal system in Laravel. In the tutorial it was not shown how to implement the addCredit() method of the user model class. I am a bit confuse.  Assuming I have another table to keep the record of credits like :

```
 user_credits
 ------------ 
 user_id
 credits
```

Is it good practice to write the code on user model's addCredits method to update the user_credits table? What will be the best in this case?

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     *  Add bonus to the user
     */
    public function addCredits($credit) {
        //
    }
}
```

The listener class to handle addition of the bonus for both the users.

```php
namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\UserReferred;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class RewardUser
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  UserReferred $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserReferred $event)
    {
        $referral = \App\ReferralLink::find($event->referralId);
        if (!is_null($referral)) {
            \App\ReferralRelationship::create(['referral_link_id' => $referral->id, 'user_id' => $event->user->id]);

            if ($referral->program->name === 'Sign-up Bonus') {
                // User who was sharing link
                $provider = $referral->user;
                // add credits to provider
                $provider->addCredits(15);
                // User who used the link
                $user = $event->user;
                $user->addCredits(20);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in my opinion it is not the best practice, but the question is philosophical. i prefer abstract such actions into a standalone service

Comment: Would you please give some hints or links where I can study further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure, is it good practice or not, but i prefer abstract such things into a standalone service.

In your case it would be something like that:

**CreditService**

```php
namespace App\Services;

use App\User;

class CreditService
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function addCredits($credits)
    {
        $this->user->credits += $credits;
        $this->user->save();
    }
}
```

Then in **controller/listener** you can work with this service

```php
use App\Services\CreditService;

...

public function handle(UserReferred $event)
{
    $referral = \App\ReferralLink::find($event->referralId);
    if ( !is_null($referral) ) {
        \App\ReferralRelationship::create([
            'referral_link_id' => $referral->id, 
            'user_id' => $event->user->id,
        ]);

        if ( $referral->program->name === 'Sign-up Bonus' ) {
            (new CreditService($referral->user))->addCredits(15);
            (new CreditService($event->user))->addCredits(20);
        }
    }
}
```

The way how you make and then use service might be different. So, if you don't want work via constructors, you can write static class and pass `User` into method directly.

I often put some additional actions into services. For example, fire events when i need to do it. Or log some things.